# Manually updating Excel worksheets through VBA doesn't work when automatic calculating is disabled

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-excel-365

In our daily work we disable automatic calculation in Excel by VBA,
and decide when a cell or sheet is updated.

`Worksheets("Sheet1").Calculate` does not seem to work any more after the update released on February 12th, 2019. See the following link:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4462115/description-of-the-security-update-for-excel-2016-february-12-2019

I've tested this in Office 2013 and 2016/365;
it still works in 2013, but not in 2016/365.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

***NB***: Current workaround is to define a range to be updated
instead of the entire sheet, which works fine.

Comment: Just checking. Events  and Screen update are set to T? `Application.EnableEvents = True : Application.ScreenUpdating = True` and does `CTRL+F9` works? if yes, then `SendKeys "{F9}"` after activating `Sheet1` should work

Comment: What Event you are using since this is  **decide when a cell or sheet is updated.** what you have written !! Try this  as Subroutine  `Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic` ☺